# customize plasma notes background color (in Kubuntu)

Tags: kde, colors, plasma-5, notes

I'd like to change the **background color** of my **plasma notes**.
I know that with knotes is possible change the background color, but I believe that plasma notes are better (I had also problems with knotes).

I notice that plasma notes are html files, stored in local/share/plasma_notes, and with css I was able to change the color and the size of text; but not the background (the changed file is always restored without background changes).

So yesterday I tried to see how I could change the background. I copied "/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notes" in my home, and changed something, f.e. I tried to add this row:

```
style: PlasmaStyle.TextAreaStyle {  
backgroundColor: plasmoid.configuration.color === "yellow" ? "#c7c5bd" : "#c7c5bd"  
}
```

But without success.
I tried also to change the file 40.colors (in usr/share/kde4/config), adding this row

```
239 237 228 Claro
```

And using "claro" as color name in plasma notes, but without success.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: In Kubuntu 18.04, there's a choice of eight preset background colors.

Comment: I know: I'm looking for other colors.

Comment: `backgroundColor` sounds wrong to me actually the whole format you gave is not css as I know it. this must be some halfway format made by KDE. did you find that variable name already there or did you type it in?

Comment: the second one (I didn't find it)...

Comment: This evening I siccessfully tried this: in html file I added in body style="background:#c7c5bd; margin:0px; padding: 2px;" And that somehow **works**.

Comment: The system has changed the code: doesn't accept changes in "style" tag, instead it added a "bgcolor" tag, not as flexible as style, but the background is still *quite* as I wanted...